# How to Select from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to compare json data being streamed in from websockets.

An array like this would work flawlessly:

```
["stream","apple","orange"]
```

But an array of arrays not so well:

```
[["stream","apple","orange"],["stream","pear","kiwi"],["stream","apple","juice"]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
function handler(jsonString) {

    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);

    if (json[0] == "blah") {
       //Do something
    }

    else if (json[0] == "blah2") {
        //Do something else
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

First reference which inner Array you want `[0]` from the outer, then using the same square bracket notation, reference the item in that inner Array  `[0][1]`.

```
if (json[0][0] == "blah") {
   //Do something
}
else if (json[0][1] == "blah2") {
    //Do something else
}
```

So the following examples would produce this:

```
json[0][0];  // "stream"
json[0][1];  // "apple"

json[1][0];  // "stream"
json[1][1];  // "pear"

// etc...
```

---

To iterate over all the items in the Arrays, you'd need a loop inside a loop. The outer one to iterate through the Arrays stored in the outer Array, and the inner loop to iterate through the values of those inner Arrays.

Like this:

```
for( var i = 0, len_i = json.length; i < len_i; i++ ) {
    for( var j = 0, len_j = json[ i ].length; j < len_j; j++ ) {
        // do something with json[ i ][ j ]; (the value in the inner Array)
    }
}
```

or if you wanted [`jQuery.each()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
jQuery.each( json, function(i,val) {
    jQuery.each( val, function(j,val_j) {
        // do something with val_j (the value in the inner Array)
    });
});
```

I'd prefer the `for` loops though.

Comment: I'm trying to find the best way to iterate through the array of arrays and tie each in to a variable
that I can use to replace data on the page. Should I use $.each for this type of function?


else if (json[0][0] == "stream") {
    //Do something else

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var stream = json[i];
    var fruit1 = stream[1];
    var fruit2 = stream[2];

alert(fruit1);

}
}

Comment: @DrEval: You'd need to do a loop inside of a loop. Yes you can use `$.each`, or just a simple `for` loop. Although I'm not certain why you would want a bunch of variables. The Array storage mechanism is designed to *prevent* the need for multiple variables. Is it for all the values? Or just certain ones? I'll give an example of looping in a minute.

Comment: @DrEval use a for loop to iterate the array, unless you have a specific need, performance is better.